# How to solve problems with unnumbered parts in TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, parts

I have following curious problem with unnumbered part (`\part*{}`).

---

All chapters are unnumbered (they have own names, so numbering is a bit useless; and also, I don't know how to avoid prefix `Chapter ...` from chapter name) and additional adding to TOC runs well.

```
\chapter*{Nové místo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nové místo}
```

TOC calls correct page number of chapter's beginning.

---

Chapters are arranged to parts. Three parts, containing the story, are numbered.

```
\part{Vetřelci}
\part{Domowina I}
\part{Stvoření světa}
```

They look in menu like that:
[image: Correct part page numbering]

But currently the fourth part is unnumbered - because it contains list of important characters from story and brief informations about them and some other similar informations.

```
\part*{Dodatky}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Dodatky}
```

Problem is, that TOC calls incorrect page of part beginning. Instead number of page where part name really stands, it calls number of page of the first chapter inside of this part.

So, in TOC is one page called twice - even if part name stands solo on page. And chapter begins on next page. Like that:
[image: Wrong part page numbering]

---

### Minimal Working Exemple

```latex
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\pagestyle{plain}

\author{Václav Macůrek}
\title{Vzpomínky na Kouzelný svět}
\date{nikdy}

\maketitle

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\part{Vetřelci}
\chapter{AAAAA}
\part{Domowina I}
\chapter{BBBBB}
\part{Stvoření světa}
\chapter{CCCCC}

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\part*{Dodatky}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Dodatky}


\chapter*{Nové místo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nové místo}
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

The unnumbered part "Dodatky" is on page 7:
[image]

But on page 8 in the Table of contents:
[image]

If I replace `book` class with `scrbook` class (to allow using of \addpart for unnumbered part called Dodatky), many (mostly bold, as I saw) texts use different (very ugly) font than I set. And also, page numbers are on left or right side of page instead center (that was my option).

Comment: Please modify your code so it can be compilable. We don't have the externals tex files Verelci etc. For example, replace `\include{./TeX_files/Vetrelci}` by `\part{Vetřelci}`. You can also delete some package calls, for exemple **graphicx** isn't used here. So you provide a MWE, minimal working exemple (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), and this helps us to help you. Also, you have two times the page 2 in your document, I suggest you to add `\pagenumbering{roman}` right after `\begin{document}`, and  `\pagenumbering{arabic}` right after `\mainmatter`.

Comment: It is possible to have a chapter number and not show it.

Comment: @WillieWong: I use (correct) order: \part -> \chapter -> \section -> \pargraph. I paid attention to avoid wrong order. And package `titlesec` doesn't meet my needs.

Comment: @quark67: Thanks for hint about pagenumbering. Package `graphicx`: you may see it unused, but without it, design is broken. MWE: thanks, I will try to add some images of it.

Comment: @Václav I will edit your code, with a very minimal exemple that shows your problem. Feel free to revert the edit if it doesn't meet your expectations. Unfortunately I don't have any clue to how to resolve your problem. You are right about **graphicx**, it is strangely needed for the b5paper format (strange because book.cls define it).

Comment: @Václav: For your part numbering issue, use `\cleardoublepage \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Dodatky}\part*{Dodatky}`.

Comment: @quark67: Thanks.  I have to say I looked on that link, but I did not understand what is (really) important to provide it (respectively, what is important to make MWE from code) - from that text.

Comment: @Václav As you can see from your edited question, what is really important in your problem is to provide some sectioning commands (parts and chapter) and one starred-part command, without any real text between. It is suffisant to show the wrong page number for the starred-part in the genered table of content. It's minimal, it's working (compilable) and it's an exemple of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `secnumdepth` to `-2`, so also parts are unnumbered. No `*` necessary in `\backmatter`.

(The `book` class doesn't really expect that `\part` is used in `\backmatter`.)

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\pagestyle{plain}

\author{Václav Macůrek}
\title{Vzpomínky na Kouzelný svět}
\date{nikdy}

\maketitle

\mainmatter
%\pagenumbering{arabic} % unnecessary
\part{Vetřelci}
\chapter{AAAAA}
\part{Domowina I}
\chapter{BBBBB}
\part{Stvoření světa}
\chapter{CCCCC}

\backmatter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\part{Dodatky}


\chapter{Nové místo}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\mainmatter` does `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, so it's not necessary to repeat the instruction.